# Flat List inside a Gesture Detector

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-gesture-handler

This code creates a custom bottomsheet and it contains a flatlist. The bottomsheet uses gesture detector to animate horizontally which fills the screen. The issue I am facing is that the as the gesture detector is active, the flatlist inside it becomes inaccessible. **So how can I disable gesture detector under certain conditions so that the flat list inside it can be accessible?**

```
const Spot = () => {
  const translateY = useSharedValue(0);
  const context = useSharedValue({ y: 0 });
  const gesture = Gesture.Pan()
    .onStart(() => {
      context.value = { y: translateY.value };
    })
    .onUpdate((event) => {
      translateY.value = event.translationY + context.value.y;
      translateY.value = Math.max(translateY.value, MAX_TRANSLATAE_Y);
    })
    .onEnd(() => {
      if (translateY.value < -deviceHeight / 1.5) {
        translateY.value = withSpring(MAX_TRANSLATAE_Y, { damping: 50 });
      } else {
        translateY.value = withSpring(-deviceHeight / 3, { damping: 50 });
      }
    });

  const rModal = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const borderRadius = interpolate(
      translateY.value,
      [MAX_TRANSLATAE_Y + 50, MAX_TRANSLATAE_Y],
      [25, 5],
      Extrapolate.CLAMP
    );
    const width = interpolate(
      translateY.value,
      [MAX_TRANSLATAE_Y + 300, MAX_TRANSLATAE_Y],
      [deviceWidth - 20, deviceWidth],
      Extrapolate.CLAMP
    );
    return {
      borderRadius,
      width,
      transform: [{ translateY: translateY.value }],
    };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    translateY.value = withSpring(-deviceHeight / 3, { damping: 50 });
    if (data !== null) {
      setIsLoading(false); // Update loading state when data fetching is done

    }
  }, []);
  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="green" />
      </View>
    );
  }
  return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white" }}>
        <GestureDetector gesture={gesture}>
          <Animated.View style={[styles.modal, rModal]}>
            <FlatList
              showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
              data={data}
              style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 20 }}
              renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                return (
                    <Text>Sample Text</Text>
                );
              }}
            />
          </Animated.View>
        </GestureDetector>
      </View>
  );
};
```

One solution which was provided was to wrap it inside GestureHandlerRootView but it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

"I solved this issue by utilizing the FlatList from the 'react-native-gesture-handler' package."

Comment: as far as I see from documentation this is deprecated API 

Consider using the new gestures API instead. The old API is not actively supported and is not receiving the new features. Check out RNGH 2.0 section in Introduction for more information.

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/gesture-handlers/about-handlers/#using-native-components